# Does parquet fileformat ALWAYS MUST have schema saved in it (with data types) and a header?

Tags: python, file, apache-spark, parquet

When saving data to Parquet file format - does Schema with Data Types MUST be saved inside Parquet file format as well? (or can be skipped)

Also - does header needs to be saved as well? (or can be skipped)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will always need a schema for a Parquet file as they are binary and without a schema couldn't be deserialized by a reader.

Not that Parquet does not really have a header but a footer. All metadata (incl. schema) is saved at the end of the file. See the following image for the structure of a Parquet file:

[image: Parquet file format structure]

Source: https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/